# How to get Id from IList<model> within model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there a simple way to get an id from an IList within another model? Preferably using razor? I want to get the RoleId within IList Roles.

```c#
    public class EditUserViewModel
    {

        public EditUserViewModel()
        {
            Claims = new List<string>(); Roles = new List<string>();
        }

        public string Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string City { get; set; }

        public List<string> Claims { get; set; }

        public IList<string> Roles { get; set; }

    }
}


   public class ManageUserRoleViewModel
    {

            public string RoleId { get; set; }
            public string RoleName { get; set; }
            public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
            //Viewbag is used to store UserId

    }

   public class UserRoleViewModel
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
        //Viewbag is used to store UserId

    }
```

```html
  <table class="table table-hover table-md ">

                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="text-left TableHead">Role</td>
                                        <td class="text-right TableHead">Delete</td>

                                    </tr>
                                </thead>

                                @*--Table Body For Each to pull DB records--*@
                                <tbody>
                                    @foreach (var role in Model.Roles)
                                    {
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>@role</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <button class="sqButton btnRed float-right zIndex" id="Delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="ajax-modal" data-target="#deleteRoleUser" data-url="@Url.Action("Delete", "Administration", new {Id = Model.Id , Type = "roleUser"})">
                                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
                                                </button>
                                            </td>

                                        </tr>
                                    }
                                </tbody>

                            </table>
```

I am trying to pass the Role Id with the other params in the @Url.Action but I can't seem to figure out the secret to pull it in, so i can pass it to the back end controller.

Comment: But your `Model.Roles` list items don't have a RoleId, because it's a `List<string>`...

Comment: In `EditUserViewModel` you'd have to use a full `Role` object and not just a `string`, like this: `public class EditUserViewModel { /* ... */ public IList<Role> Roles { get; set; } }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that

`public IList<string> Roles { get; set; }`

Contains only strings, so there's no ID to look for. You would have to change this  line to

`public IList<ManageUserRoleViewModel> Roles { get; set; }`

This way, you have a list of objects that also hold an ID. Then, in your view, you can do this:

`@Model.Roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.RoleId == YOUR_UNIQUE_ID)`

This will give you an object to perform further logic on.

Comment: If it helps please choose this as the correct answer. :)

Comment: just did! wanted to make sure first. One more small thing the == YOUR_UNIQUE_ID, i was assuming it could be anything. But it's giving me 'does not exist in this context'. it's a terribly ignorant question but I am struggling.

Comment: I'm assuming you have an integer or a string somewhere that you want to look for. Replace "YOUR_UNIQUE_ID" with that and you'll be done. 

If you want to use `role` inside the `@foreach` statement in your Razor view, you have to do so inside the curly braces.